# Where can I get a jQuery carousel plugin that allows me to adjust its height dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Many of the most popular ones I have tried restrict the height.

jCarousel for sure does & Tiny Carousel just didn't work for me.

Anyone have any suggestions on what other plugin might work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tiny Carousel you can set the height dynamically with a callback.

```
var oSlider = $('#slider-code');
oSlider.tinycarousel({
    callback: function(element){
            element.css({ 'height': 100 });
            $('.viewport', oSlider).css({ 'height': 100});
    }
});
```

Something like this havent tested so there could be a bug :P.
Replace the 100 with the height you need;

Answer (score 1):

Using a callback, you can resize the height of focused page dynamically - based on the element height (no need to enter manual height values):

```
$('#slider').tinycarousel({
  controls: false,
  pager: true,
  animation: false,
  callback: function(e){
    $('.viewport').css({'height': ($(e).height() + 10) +'px'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try building something custom based on the Cycle plugin... Beyond that youll have to elaborate a tab more on the restricting of height and the issues youve run in to.

Comment: Funny you should suggest that. That was actually the road I started off - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408865/how-do-i-modify-the-jquery-cycle-plugin-for-a-two-image-slideshow-instead-of-one - but I got the suggestions from the creator of that plugin, that I should be using a Carousel plugin, rather than a slideshow plugin.

Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: Well his comment makes sense but at the same time i think he was commenting coming from the perspective of its more efficient to use a plugin that alread has the proper list/queue behavior like jCarousel as opposed to trying to add it to cycle. however since you need dynamic height youre i think this is not the case. It would be much harder to modify a carousel to account for that than to add the "paging" animation around Cycle.But hopefully someone will chime in with a carousel that has all you need :-)